# What is arg type for concurrency::task::then?

Tags: c++11, concurrency, visual-studio-2013, c++-cx

```
IAsyncOperation<Foo^>^ op = ...;
auto theTask = concurrency::create_task(op);
```

What now?

```
theTask.then([](concurrency::task<Foo^> arg)
```

or

```
theTask.then([](Foo^ arg)
```

The compiler does not generate an error and I get exception in run-time (for both cases). But this exception can be related to different reasons and I want to be sure that my syntax is correct at least.

Comment: This does not seem to be valid C++11 syntax.

Comment: @Ali You are right, I updated tags. It's C++/CX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `then` method takes a callable object (such as a lambda expression) taking the element type of the async operation, or a task of that type. Hence, either of the following will work:

```
theTask.then([](Foo^ arg) { return 0; });
```

or

```
theTask.then([](concurrency::task<Foo^> arg) { return 0; });
```

Notice the code in your question was missing the body of the lambda expression and the closing parenthesis (as in, `{ body; })`).